# Construct Sets in Coq

Tags: coq

How to construct elements of the following set(assuming A : Set)?

A -> A + A

My answer is following:

```
Definition set : A -> A + A :=
fun a => match a with
         | inl l => a
         | inr r => a
         end.
```

And it returns:

```
Error: In environment
P, Q, R : Prop
A, B, C : Set
a : A
The term "a" has type "A" while it is expected to have type "?T + ?T0".
```

Comment: If you're matching `a` against `inl` and `inr`, then it must be that `a : ?1 + ?2`. Instead what you want to do is just pick whether this `a` will be wrapped inside `inl` or `inr`.

Comment: Could you edit your question to be more precise ? You want to build a term a type `A -> A + A` but your solution has type `A+A -> A+A`. It seems to me you have something backwards

Comment: Why not simply `Definition set : A -> A + A := inl.` (Or `inr`.)

Comment: @MarkDickinson I have tried this and it returns "The term "inl" has type "forall A B : Type, A -> A + B" while it is expected to have type 
"A -> A + A" (cannot unify "A" and "Type")". I revised the your answer to Definition set : A -> A + A := fun a => inl a. (Or inr a). It works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understand your problem correctly, but here's a solution.

```
Definition mkset {A : Set}: A -> A + A.
  intro a.
  left.
  assumption.
Defined.
```

The idea is to use tactics to build a function of type `A -> A + A`. Tactic `intro` corresponds to abstraction of parameter `a`. Tactic `left` allows us to choose to prove just the left hand side of `A + A`. Finally, `assumption` search the hypothesis for a proposition that fits the current goal and finish it, if such hypothesis exists in context.

Comment: Thx but not the right answer. I mean how to construct A -> A + A instead of how to prove. The format is Definition mkset : A -> A + A := something.

Comment: So the answer would be: `Definition mkset {A : Set}: A -> A + A := fun (a : A) := inl a.`

Comment: So the answer would be: `Definition mkset {A : Set}: A -> A + A := fun (a : A) := inl a.`. Note that, as @Ptival said, `Definition set : A -> A + A :=
fun a => match a with
         | inl l => a
         | inr r => a
         end. ` is incorrect because in the `match` the type of `a` must be a `?T + T'`. I'm not a Coq expert, but to me, the unique way to build a term of type `A -> A + A` is using tactics like I've put in previous answer or like above in this comment.

Comment: You are right. I just modified your solution to "Definition mkset : A -> A + A := fun a => inl a. (Or inr a)". Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Please, mark it as an answer to your question.